# Migration of site

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, migration

I have a sharepoint 2007 site which I want to migrate to sharepoint 2013 can someone provide a resource, any URL for Tutorial.

Let me know, if Its possible to migrate a site to 2013 from sharepoint 2007 or do we have to first migrate it to 2010 and then to 2013.

Thanks.
RHM

Answer (score 4):

You cannot migrate from 2007 to 2013. You need to migrate to 2010 first and then migrate to 2013.  More on this  :- 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262483(v=office.15).